# Laravel Carbon, set specific hours:minutes:seconds

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I have a Carbon date like:

```
$new_days_count = Carbon::now();

dd($new_days_count);

Carbon {#764 ▼
  +"date": "2019-07-20 19:06:49.119790"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "UTC"
}
```

Now, I want to set a specific hours:minutes:seconds to that time, in order to have:

```
Carbon {#764 ▼
  +"date": "2019-07-20 23:59:59.000000"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "UTC"
}
```

How can I set it? I want to set always at `23:59:59.000000`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For your specific use case, this should do:

```
Carbon\Carbon::now()->endOfDay()
```

You can also more generally use the [setters](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-setters):

```
$new_days_count->hour = 23;
$new_days_count->minute = 59;
$new_days_count->second = 59;
```

or

```
$new_days_count->hour(23);
$new_days_count->minute(59);
$new_days_count->second(59);
```

or `$new_days_count->setHour(23)` or `$new_days_count->set('hour', 23)`. Don't ask me why there are twelve different ways of doing it; they all do the same thing, so pick the one you like the look of.

(If you *really* care about the microseconds, you can also do `$new_days_count->micro(0)` to set that to zero.)

Comment: Thanks, I found on the documentation that `endOfDay()` method and did what I need. Nice to read the other ways too.

Comment: Important to note: All three of those RETURN an updated instance. It doesn't seem to update the instance itself. I had to do `$new_days_count = $new_days_count->hour(23)` in order to actually update the instance.

Answer (score 3):

Like @ceejayoz mentionned, for your use case `endOfDay()` is what your need.

If you encouter a use case where you need to set a specific time (i.e 22:32:05), you could use the fluent setter `setTimeFromTimeString('22:32:05')` instead of chaining `hour(22)->minute(32)->second(5)`.